# Counting sort using STL

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, sorting

I'm trying to learn to use the C++ Standard Library and some of the modern C++11 features. Can someone review my counting sort algorithm below and critique my style/algorithm/use of the STL? Thank you!

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

const int kSize = 100000000;      // Size of container to sort
const int kRangeFrom = -1000000;  // first of range for random number generator
const int kRangeTo = 1000000;     // last of range for random number generator

// Linear time sorting algorithm for integers
template<typename InputIterator>
void counting_sort(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
  auto minmax_el = std::minmax_element(first, last);
  auto min = *minmax_el.first;
  auto max = *minmax_el.second;
  std::vector<std::size_t> counts(max - min + 1, 0);

  std::for_each(first, last, [&](auto x) { 
    ++counts[x - min];  // Store value counts
  }); 

  for (auto it_c = counts.begin(); it_c != counts.end(); ++it_c) { 
    auto idx = std::distance(counts.begin(), it_c);
    std::fill_n(first, *it_c, idx + min); // Store in sorted order
    std::advance(first, *it_c);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 mt(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(kRangeFrom,kRangeTo);

  std::vector<int> v1(kSize);
  std::generate(v1.begin(), v1.end(), [&](){ return dist(mt); });

  std::vector<int> v2(kSize);
  std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin());

  auto first1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  counting_sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
  auto last1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  auto first2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
  auto last2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  std::cout << "counting sort time: " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(last1 - first1).count() << " ms" << '\n';
  std::cout << "std::sort time: " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(last2 - first2).count() << " ms" << '\n';
  std::cout << "v1 == v2: " << std::equal(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin()) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Associative container

Update: Because of the O(n.log(n)) nature of std::map we have concluded this is not a good idea (But it was worth the test).

Rather than using a vector to store the count you can use an associative container.

```
std::vector<std::size_t> counts(max - min + 1, 0);

// replace with 

using ValueType = std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type;
std::map<ValueType, std::size_t>  counts;
```

1. This will limit the amount of memory you use otherwise the amount of space you use could potentially exceed memory.
2. Also iterating over a sparse array would be expensive (As there will be lots of zero counts). By using an associative container you only iterate over valid values.

### Range based for

Use the new range based for.

```
for (auto it_c = counts.begin(); it_c != counts.end(); ++it_c) {

// replace with:

for(auto const& value: counts) {
```

### Combine range based for and associative containers

```
void counting_sort(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    using ValueType = std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type;
    std::map<ValueType, std::size_t> counts;

    for(auto value: boost::make_iterator_range(first, last)) { 
        ++counts[value];
    }

    for(auto count: counts) {
        ValueType&   value = count.first;
        std::size_t& size  = count.second;  
        std::fill_n(first, size, value);
        std::advance(first, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The map makes it a lot cleaner but I think it makes it O(nlogn) rather than O(n). `++counts[value];` runs pretty slowly

Comment: I would replace the order-based log2(n) insertion-time `std::map` with it's hash-table equivalent (and thus O(1) amortized insertion time) `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @Bizkit: Unfortunately that's not going to work. As the map iterators are ordered while the unordered_map iterators are unordered. We are relying on the property of ordered to get the sort to work.

Comment: @ryan: You are correct. But because of the property of sparseness your code is only `O(n)` for large values of `n`. For small values of `n` the complexity is more like `O(range(n))`. I would add a check for small ranges `if (std::distance(first, last) < 1000000)  {std::sort(first, last);return}`.

Comment: Thanks. I could also turn it into radix sort to fix the sparseness problem.

Answer (score 3):

Counting sort is an excellent tool when you know that you will be sorting integer values in a tight range, so I would keep it as is with its « problems » instead of trying to turn it into a more generic algorithm. If you want a more flexible integer sorting algorithm, radix sort would be the way to go :)

However, while keeping the spirit and simplicity of counting sort, there are still several small things you can do to make it better:

- [`InputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) is never a suitable iterator category for an inplace sorting algorithm since input iterators are single-pass, which means that it's not guaranteed that you can write values back into them once you have read them. Your `counting_sort` implementation even reads the iterated values several times. The iterator category you want is [`ForwardIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator).

  *Note: it might be a mere hint for the reader today, but this kind of thing will be even more meaningful when concepts will be included into the language.*
- You can return early and save memory when the original collection is already sorted: while the standard library does not provide such a function (it's too specific), it is possible to perform `std::minmax_element` and `std::is_sorted` at once without any significant additional cost. You can find such a function in [Boost.Sort `spreadsort` implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/sort/blob/develop/include/boost/sort/spreadsort/detail/integer_sort.hpp#L34-L57):

  ```
  template <class RandomAccessIter>
  inline bool
  is_sorted_or_find_extremes(RandomAccessIter current, RandomAccessIter last,
                             RandomAccessIter & max, RandomAccessIter & min)
  {
    min = max = current;
    //This assumes we have more than 1 element based on prior checks.
    while (!(*(current + 1) < *current)) {
      //If everything is in sorted order, return
      if (++current == last - 1)
        return true;
    }

    //The maximum is the last sorted element
    max = current;
    //Start from the first unsorted element
    while (++current < last) {
      if (*max < *current)
        max = current;
      else if (*current < *min)
        min = current;
    }
    return false;
  }
  ```

  Just make sure beforehand that `fist != last` if you don't want surprises due to dereferencing iterators that theoretically point to nowhere.
- `std::advance` is \$O(n)\$ for forward iterators and bidirectional iterators, which means that if you want to sort an `std::list` or an `std::forward_list` with your `counting_sort`, you will end advancing twice the same iterator in \$O(n)\$ with the following lines:

  ```
  std::fill_n(first, size, value);
  std::advance(first, size);
  ```

  This is a waste of time since [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) has already computed the iterator where to advance `first` internally. Fortunately, since C++11, `std::fill_n` returns the iterator past the last element assigned, so you can simply turn the two lines above into a single more efficient one:

  ```
  first = std::fill_n(first, size, value);
  ```

  Now `counting_sort` should be a bit more efficient when given forward or bidirectional iterators.